# How would I change the appearance of a webpage using WebView?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, webview

I have a method that, when called, opens up a web page using WebView

```
public void open() {

        myWebViewV = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(myWebViewV);

        myWebViewV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });
        myWebViewV.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.org");

    }
```

this loads the web page just fine and kind of does what I want it to do but.. the page it self has a few things that I want to get rid of.

for example, it has "reply" and "post" or "quote" buttons the user can press to reply, post or quote someone.

my goal is to implement these my self and hide the website's buttons.

Is this possible using the WebView class? 
Is there another class that I have to use to accomplish this?
I did look through WebView but found nothing that could provide me with the tool's needed to do this.

googling didn't help much either, but thats probably because I couldn't articulate my intent properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by injecting javascript into to the webpage you're loading.

```
final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);

// enable JavaScript
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // here you can do whatever you want
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByTagName('reply_button').style.display='none'; " +
                "})()");
    }
});

webview.loadUrl("http://www.webiste.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible using the WebView class?

Perhaps. You can execute JavaScript in the context of the loaded Web page, and so if you can craft JavaScript that does what you want to the DOM, you can do that with a `WebView`.

On Android 4.3 and below, use `loadUrl("javascript:...")`, where `...` is replaced by your JavaScript source code.

On Android 4.4 and above, use `evaluateJavascript()`.

Comment: at the risk of sounding stupid.. I don't know any javascript.. would I have to actually learn it to properly build something like what I want?

Or are there built in methods I can use that would aid with this..

Comment: @SpaceGhost: "would I have to actually learn it to properly build something like what I want?" -- yes. "Or are there built in methods I can use that would aid with this" -- the built-in methods are JavaScript, within the browser.